# R - Faster alternative to function apply

Tags: r, performance, apply

My script spends most of the time processing the function apply. Could you recommend me a faster alternative? Here is an example of my code while I'm using apply.

```
myarrayIGvalues <- apply(myarray[,,antenna,1],2,max,na.rm=T)
```

Raúl

Comment: what's the structure of `myarray`?

Comment: Please consider posting a reproducible example and the expected result based on that.

Comment: "myarray" is an array of four dimensions. The expected results from myarrayIGvalues is a numeric vector.

Comment: without any more details about your array is hard to know how to increase the speed of your apply. Consider @akrun comment and provide us with a self contained example. __Edit: you seem to want the `max`, so maybe the suggestion is nonsense__ The only suggestion I can give is check the documentation of: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colSums.html  "These functions are equivalent to use of apply with FUN = mean or FUN = sum with appropriate margins, but are a lot faster. ". Maybe that helps.

Comment: Check *mclapply* from package **parallel**

Comment: @grubjesic how can I adapt this line with apply to mclapply? I've checked the documentation of mclapply but not guess...

Comment: As previous commentators said please share myarray with us.   Then I can write code that will run this on multi cores.

Comment: @grubjesic here is the function of myarray. In this case, the length of allepcs is 5 and length names of 24.  Please, tell me if you need more information.                                                                                      myarray<-array(NA,dim=c(length(allepcs),length(names(dades)),4,2))